# WPF DataContext value dynamic assignment

Tags: wpf, data-binding

How to set the DataContext value later in a WPF application?. Here in the below code I am setting it at the beginning (Startup). Later I would like to set another DataContext value to the view. What is the best way to do it?

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow view = new MainWindow();
        MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        view.DataContext = mainViewModel;
        view.Show();
    }

}
```

Simply telling, there is a ObservableCollection inside the MainViewModel and it is assigned when the user do some button press action only. I need that data to be updated in the view. Please let me know if you have any questions

EDIT
::::

I have an additional question too. Do I need to reassign the entire DataContext or Can I do something through INotifyCollectionChanged event? Please clarify

Comment: No need to change the DataContext, can be handled through propertychanged event

Answer (score 0):

Your mainViewModel is tightly coupled to your class MainViewModel. Try to use interface. you can create IViewModel and implement it to your MainViewModel. This site will help you
[dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)
you can also use some dependency injection like ninject.

Comment: Could you please give some samples?